# Matching of array elements in Julia

Tags: julia

With `x = Any[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]`, I tried the following line with Julia0.4.0

```
x[ x .== [3,4] ]
```

but it resulted in an error

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
```

I expected it to give something like `Any[ [3,4] ]` because

```
x[3] == [3,4]   # => true
```

is no problem. Although this operation itself may not be useful, I would like to know what the error message means. So I would appreciate any hints why this error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make an element-by-element comparison, Julia requires that both arrays have the same number of elements. This can be achieved in this case with a comprehension:

```
julia> x = Any[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 [1,2]
 [2,3]
 [3,4]
 [4,5]

julia> x[x.==[[3,4] for i in 1:length(x)]]
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 [3,4]
```

So the question in my mind was "why doesn't Julia broadcast the `[3,4]` into this shape automatically?". The following example is broadcast correctly:

```
julia> y = [1,2,3,4]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> y.==3
4-element BitArray{1}:
 false
 false
  true
 false

julia> y[y.==3]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
```

It appears that Julia's broadcast mechanism is unable to infer that we want `[3,4]` to be broadcast into `[[3,4],[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]]` rather than some other shape of array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Now I understand what "broadcast" means in this error message. I also confirmed that `@show x[ x .== [ [3,4] for i = 1:length(x) ] ] => Any[[3,4]]` (this is already a big surprise for me!) Similarly, `x .== 1`, ` x .== "hi"`, and `x .== [1]` all worked (giving an empty `Any[]`). So it looks Julia is not happy with this `[3,4]` or similar ones...

Answer (score 3):

You can help Julia a little in figuring out how to broadcast the second variable by writing the comparison like this:

```
julia> x .== Any[[3, 4]]
```

You get a BitArray out as expected:

```
4-element BitArray{1}:
 false
 false
  true
 false
```

So indexing with the result of the comparison works too:

```
julia> x[ x .== Any[[3,4]] ]
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 [3,4]
```